# How can I install google-chrome-stable on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS?

Tags: software-installation, google-chrome

When I'm going to install the Google Chrome,it says on the Ubuntu Software Center that `Dependency is not satisfiable: libappindicator1`

[image]

Comment: run `sudo apt-get install -f` in terminal.

Comment: I've already done it,but nothing is changed.Can you tell me the details please?

Comment: but it still says "Dependency is not satisfiable: libappindicator1"

Comment: sudo apt-get install `libappindicator1` ? Did running this command install `libappindicator1` without any errors?

Comment: Don't install Google Chrome from the repository. It might be old. Use the .deb from the website. Just for convenience: https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html

Comment: This might fix. Install it by opening the terminal and type `sudo dpkg -i <deb file name>`. Here's the link http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libs/libappindicator1

Comment: @dattutbrus - Look at the screenshot. Its the latest version.

Comment: @Raphael try manually installing the `libappindicator1` then

Comment: @Tim Not strictly a duplicate. This is a more of "unmet dependency" issue

Comment: @Serg Hmm maybe...

Comment: OP, please provide `apt-cache policy libappindicator1` output

Answer (score 0):

Ok first of all update Ubuntu's software repositories by using the command after opening the terminal

> sudo apt-get update

After that download the .deb file of google chrome from here

> https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html

After that just double click the downloaded file it should open the Ubuntu software Center and the installation will take place.

I think it should work.Try it once..:)
After the installation you can open google chrome using the command in terminal

> google-chrome-stable

Answer (score 0):

You can try `apt-get --no-install-recommends install pkgname`. This installs without suggests.. You can install the suggests (dependencies) for a single package installation by using `apt-get -o APT::Install-Suggests="true" install pkgname`.